# Python/PHP Libraries for processing keynote presentations

Tags: php, python, image-processing, keynote

I need to extract slides out of a keynote presentation as images. Is there any python/PHP library out there that helps with this? ImageMagick works with PDFs. I would like to know if there's one which works with keynote.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the closest I've found: http://petercorke.com/Keynote.html, but haven't had a  chance to test it yet!